# Google Adword not working /conversion.js not found

Tags: wordpress, google-ads-api

I'm currently working on a wordpress site. My task is just to add the conversion script in a thankyou page. I added the script here: http://www.livingedge.co.nz/thanks-for-getting-in-touch/ , unfortunately does not work. It says that a conversion.js was not found.

See the attached screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/52ixQUzHKNxZ

I added the conversion script on the footer put it in a conditional so that it will load only on the thakyoupage.

I'm new to this and can't figure out what would be the possible cause of such problem. 
I tried adding the script in the header, on the page editor, on a form redirect.

**Q: What could be the possible cause of this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are using for the conversion script is incorrect — the correct one has "www" in the domain name.

The fact that you've got this link wrong makes me think you may be looking at incorrect directions.
Follow the instructions given in the Google documentation page "[Setting up conversion tracking](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en)" precisely.

Comment: The code was just given to me by my colleague, copy and pasted it. 
I just added a 'www' to the link, and it works now!. Thanks a lot duskwuff for the hint. http://screencast.com/t/3csikrWR9

Comment: I would strongly recommend that, when possible, you go back to the documentation and generate a new code snippet from the Google AdWords site. There may be other issues with the code you've been given.